# Disable all menu items

Tags: vb.net

How to disable all menu items in context menu which contain separator item?

My approach:

```
    For Each item As ToolStripMenuItem In ContextMenuStrip1.Items
        item.Enabled = False
    Next
```

work good if I haven't separator in menu but with separator I get error:

> Unable to cast object of type 'System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripSeparator' to type 'System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripMenuItem'.

How to disable all items in menu which contain separator item?

Comment: You might try looping through all the items and then use a Select or If statement for menu items and separators.

Comment: @tim - beat me to it.. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Code example (untested) to illustrate my comment:

```
For i = 0 To ContextMenuStrip1.Items.Count - 1
    If TypeOf ContextMenuStrip1.Items(i) Is ToolStripMenuItem Then
        CType(ContextMenuStrip1.Items(i), ToolStripMenuItem).Enabled = False
    End If
Next
```

Basically you go through all the items in the menu, and if the current item is of type `ToolStripMenuItem` you disable it.